# Best way to encode categorical data(URLs) in large dataset in Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, svm, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I have a large dataset where one of the feature is categorical(nominal) named URL which conatins different URLs. For example, www.google.com, www.facebook.com, www.youtube.com, www.yahoo.com, www.amazon.com, etc. There are more than 500 different URLs in a million rows.

Which is the best way to encode this categorical feature so that I can pass the encoded feature to Logistic Regression model?

I have tried using label encoding from sklearn but it didn't work well as just labeling the URLs with 1, 2, 3,... doesn't form any relation between them.

I tought of using one hot encoding but it will create 500+ new feature for my model and unnecessarily increase the complexity of the model.

Code and data is confidential, I can't provide.

Label encoding didn't work well and one-hot encoding will make the model too complex.

Answer (score 0):

I would first ask if this variable is completely necessary? Is it something that can be dropped?

If it cannot be dropped, I would do a frequency plot of the websites that appear. The websites you mention might show up significantly more than some other obscure websites. I would use the histogram to pick maybe the top 10 or 12, etc.

Comment: Yes, This variable is amongst the most important feature in the given features so it can't be dropped. So the idea is to use all the websites and not drop any. I thought of doing one-hot encdoing with rare values where the count of occurance of every unique website should be greater than 5. Doing so, I lost 30% of the data, so picking top 10 to 12 might not lead to a good solution.